# How to display input date as dd-mm-yyy

Tags: html, css, wordpress, date, input

I have an input date which is displayer in admin panel as `18.01.2021` but on site it's displayed as `2021-04-18`. How can I make it displayed on site as dd-mm-yyyy?
HTML of input:

```
   <input type="date" value="2021-04-18" name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_registration_date" class="widefat">
```

[image]

Input in php (wordpress admin panel)

```
$manager->register_control(
    'registration_date',
    array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'section' => 'stm_options',
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Приблизна дата прибуття (рік, місяць, число)', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
        'preview' => 'registration_date',
        'description' => esc_html__( 'Only in classified layout', 'stm_vehicles_listing' ),
        'attr' => array( 'class' => 'widefat' )
    )
);
```

Comment: I mean, you set `value="2021-04-18"` so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I set `18.04.2021` in input. I want to change value so it will be displayed as `18.04.2021`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format in WordPress' settings. It's under `Administration > Settings > General`.

Set your format string as `d/m/Y`.

- `d` is the day with leading zeros.
- `m` is the month with leading zeros.
- `Y` is the year in four digit format.

Comment: I had it as `d/m/Y` but it still displaying as 2021-04-17

Comment: maybe I need to add a pattern with js (I cannot add it with HTML bacause I added input with php code above)